# Opening an onclick input stored in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Currently I have something going on with my website where I am trying to store my download links behind an `input button` I am using the following php script to echo out some styled data for my download buttons.

```
$data['link'] = $link;
$data['name'] = $name;
print '<input type="button" value="скачать" onclick="window.open(''.$data['link'].'')">';
print '<input type="button" value="скачать" onclick="window.open(''.$data['link'].'')">';
```

The above is causing issues because of the `' '` brackets, what alternative solution can I do to replicate the same result, I can't load it outside of the `php` code because it would be extremely messy with the amount of download links I've got included.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the inner single quotes like `\'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't escaping the quotes in the `onclick` event. You have to add a backslash before the outer single quotes:

```
print '<input type="button" value="скачать" onclick="window.open(\''.$data['link'].'\')">';
```

But don't forget that you have to add slashes to the link to prevent errors:

```
print '<input type="button" value="скачать"
    onclick="window.open(\''. addslashes($data['link']) .'\')">';
```

**EDIT**: Since escaping quotes in html attributes using backslashes doesn't work, you have to use `htmlspecialchars()` instead of `addslashes()`. My bad!

Use this code:

```
print '<input type="button" value="скачать"
    onclick="window.open(\''. htmlspecialchars($data['link']) .'\')">';
```

This replaces `"` with `&quot;` and `'` with `&#039;`.

Comment: @Vin I just correct a mistake. You have to use htmlspecialchars.